# How to check webservice is finish perform?

Tags: android, web-services

I have a webservice that download about 100 lines data and store into local database.

Then, from database `sqlite`, it will allocate into difference list.

I want to get the response from web service when the data is downloading from server to database, either is in progress or finished and should return the status.

I need the status to do some action.

Comment: I think the get the data download limit from the web service is the best option for you to work on.Also through use can able to make one progress ui which shows user about the activity from web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AsyncTask` for downloading information from web-services to application that will take care about the response (i.e progress )
here the document : [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

tutorial : [AsyncTask - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Design it in such a way that an Intent will be broadcast upon completion. This is the cleanest way to do it, and broadcast it exclusively to your app.